# Rails - Account Activation not redirecting to https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I have my mailer sending an account activation link like the one below:

edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email)

producing:

http://MYAPPHOST/account_activation/7Apxg0G5t2V5tHrO2tatPQ/edit?email=sdf%40oiu.com

which works when I change it to https but it isn't being redirected. I already have config.force_ssl = true so I'm not sure how to enable this redirect. Any help is appreciated.

Whenever I go to http://MYAPP I get redirected to about:blank

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is in your production environment? What hosting provider and/or server are you using (Heroku, AWS, and Apache, NGINX, etc).

Check your SSL settings, for your web server, particularly the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header. When a HTTPS request comes to Apache/NGINX, they will terminate the SSL connection and send a HTTP request to Unicorn/Puma/Thin/Webrick. Your Rails server will see `protocol=HTTP` unless you set the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header. That will cause your `x_y_z_url` helpers to return `http://...` instead of `https://...`.

For example, in NGINX:

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```